# Notification tile with web image doesn't update

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

In my Windows 8 app, I have been trying to include a web image in my notification tile.  It doesn't work though - my notifications don't appear.

If I go to Control Panel->Administrative Tools->Event Viewer->Applications and Services Logs->Microsoft->Windows->Apps->Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational, I can see all of my notifications that failed.  The error message in the Event View is really unhelpful: "The processing of a tile notification has failed".

If I use a local image, my tile notifications work and appear with the image and text:

```
var wideContent = TileContentFactory.CreateTileWideSmallImageAndText03();
wideContent.TextBodyWrap.Text = "Some text";
wideContent.Image.Src = "ms-appx:///assets/myLocalImage.gif";
wideContent.RequireSquareContent = false;
var notification = wideContent.CreateNotification();
TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Update( notification );
```

If instead I do this:

```
// All the http web images I have tried have failed
wideContent.Image.Src = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ae/Ursus_arctos_-_Norway.jpg";
```

My notification doesn't appear.  (There are no exceptions or anything - my notification fails to appear in the tile, and an error appears in the Event Viewer.)

Similarly, I can't get the MS example app at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-tiles-and-badges-sample-5fc49148 to work with web images.

Is anyone else experiencing this issue or does anyone know how to resolve it?

EDIT:

The above code is using the NotificationsExtensions library from the MS sample app.  I get the same issue using XmlDocument, etc., to build the notification.  (Example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868236.aspx )

Comment: Does your app have Internet permissions? Did you try HTTPS?

Comment: I do have Internet (Client) declared as a capability in my manifest.  I just tried with HTTPS and I get the same result (no notification on my tile).

Comment: If you don't use an image, is your tile working? (e.g. is it your image part that's causing the failure)

Comment: Yeah, the tile works without the image...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the URL in your sample above is the actual image, it's too large.  I downloaded it and it was dimension 2620 x 3930.

Images can be no larger than 1024x1024 and 200KB - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh781198.aspx

Comment: I tried a smaller image - I googled "snakes" and got this one: http://content.artofmanliness.com/uploads/2008/07/coral-snake.jpg .  This also doesn't show up in the tile in the sample app...  Also to clarify, I'm just pulling random images off the web to test.

Comment: that image is working for me with the sample SDK application you quoted earlier ALTHOUGH, I had to modify the tile size from the start screen to small to see it.  Then switching back to large showed it correctly too ... not sure why that is.   Are you testing this in the simulator - you DEFINITELY have to restart the simulator to see the change (that's noted in the doc).

Comment: Wow... what a simple solution.  Makes my question appear so silly.  Modifying the size of the tile to small, then back to wide, caused the image to appear.  If you want, you could edit your answer to include that little trick.  Thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm trying to get an explanation for why it doesn't show automatically - that doesn't seem right to me.  Will update then.

Comment: images must be max 200kb not mb